# No connection to Azure IoT, delayed intermediaries

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Consider a device placed in no GSM area, i.e. underground or in a pipe or similar. Those devices needs to be updated, checked, enabled/disabled via smartphones of workers passing by. Does Azure IoT support some kind of solution to this? Meaning a smartphone would store a command to a device or to Azure IoT till it reaches connection to Web.

Comment: How does the smartphone communicate with such device?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Via low distance bluetooth, this is ibeacon.

Comment: The smartphone can store a command or not depends the app running on it. This is not related to Azure IoT Hub.